# Why is Mr. E (recent NZ rape convict) full name abbreviated in the appeal judgment?

Tags: criminal-procedure, new-zealand, anonymization

It is common practice in the U.K. to anonymise sexual assault victims’ identities in court filings, but why in this NZ case are all the parties’ names apparently withheld?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[canada](/questions/tagged/canada)

It is common to anonymize as much as necessary in order to protect the identity of the complainant. If the accused is a close relative, or other close relationship, this will often also require anonymizing the name of the accused.

See [*Criminal Code*, 486.4](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/c-46/page-69.html#docCont):

> Subject to subsection (2), the presiding judge or justice may make an order directing that **any information that could identify the victim or a witness shall not be published** in any document or broadcast or transmitted in any way, in proceedings in respect of [a large list of offences including sexual assault].

While such an order can be imposed by the court on its own, **this order is mandatory if requested by the victim, prosecutor, or witness**.

Comment: Just to be perfectly clear, this can only be requested by the VICTIM, right?

Comment: Is that the NZ criminal code?

Comment: Age plays a role too, right? Like, minor parties to a lawsuit tend to be only abbreviated by default it seems.